# jQuery Loop Though Column and Get Text

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to loop though a column in jQuery and pull the text from a particular column?

This is what my table looks like - I want to run down the column of cells with "first":

```
<tr>
  <td id="first">...</td>
  <td>...</td>
  <td>...</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Sure it is. What have you tried?

Comment: Do you want us to write this for you? Or help you fix the code you have tried?

Comment: I've found I can use $( "#tableName tr #first" ).next() however having issues in starting from index 0 of my table. i.e. how to specify the index?

Comment: If you have more than one row in your table, you will have duplicate id's on your page which is a big no-no. Use class="first" instead. Alternatively you can use a selector like `$('tr td:first-child')` to select just the first td element in each row (no id or class needed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note, you can't duplicate ID's on a page so you should be using `class="first"`.

Here is an example based on your HTML: 
[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/qd4s1jy5/)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="first">...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
<table>

$(function(){
    //variable to hold our combined data from the .first column
    var combined = "";

    //get all of the .first table cells (i.e. first column)
    var firsts = $('td.first');


    //iterate through the firsts array we just created
    firsts.each(function(){
        combined += $(this).text();    
    });

    //do whatever you want with the combined variable here
    alert(combined);

});
```

*Alternatively*, you can use the `:first-child` [CSS sudo-selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp) if you want to avoid id's and classes on the td elements all together.  
**[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/qd4s1jy5/4/)**

```
var firsts = $('tr td:first-child');
```

Comment: Thank you! I used this along with jQuery's  eq()